# Alternatives to ASTA Servers for C# and .NET tehnology

Tags: c#, .net, client, client-server

We made a great job on one project using [ASTA](http://www.astatech.com/index.asp) server. Now We want to start something similar using .Net and C#. For project we need server for handling clients and acting as middle man between database and end users.

Is there similar projects to [ASTASERVER](http://www.astaserver.com/) made for .Net environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the closest alternative in the .NET world is this one:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [RemObjects DataAbstract](http://www.remobjects.com/) will do the job?